# sql server with clause issue

Tags: sql-server, with-clause

sql below runs without problem in db2

```
with mytable(a,b) as  (
    values(
    (select current timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy1), (select current timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy1))
)
select * from mytable
```

I want to run something similar in sql server, when I give this

```
with mytable(a,b) as (
values(
(select current_timestamp), (select current_timestamp))
)
select * from mytable
```

error below raises:

> *Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'. SQLState:  S1000 ErrorCode: 156 Error: Incorrect syntax near ','. SQLState:  42000
>   ErrorCode: 102 Error: Incorrect syntax near ')'. SQLState:  42000
>   ErrorCode: 102*

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave out `values`:

```
with mytable(a, b) as (
      select current_timestamp, current_timestamp
     )
select *
from mytable;
```